# Laptop internal port identification

Tags: laptop, motherboard

I saw this port in my laptop near the WiFi card, and was wondering what it is or what it's for.  The "5SN" hasn't turned up anything helpful yet on Google, and neither has reverse image search.

[image: pic of unknown port]

There is a loose antenna cable nearby that may be for whatever card is designed to plug into this.

The laptop is a Dell Latitude E5400.

Does anyone know what kind of port it is and what it's for?

(Apologies for the blurriness; my phone doesn't like focusing that close)

Thanks!